# How do you extract number of rows in Count(*), and send to a variable. (Pl/SQL)

Tags: plsql, oracle9i, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying extract the number of rows using the count(*) with the respect of it's condition and sending it to a variable for later use.

**How do I create variables for the number of rows within a table.** 
Thank you.

```
VARIABLE 
VAR CHAR(10)

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :VAR 

FROM [Database]
WHERE [condition 1]
AND [condition 2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use PL/SQL to do the select:

```
SQL> variable var number
SQL> begin
  2     select count(*)
  3     into :var
  4     from all_tables
  5     where owner = user;
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print var

       VAR
----------
       163
```

Comment: I keep on getting this Script                                                  Output "Bind Variable "var" is NOT DECLARED
anonymous block completed"

Answer (score 0):

What about passing the result of the whole query to the variable?

```
VARIABLE 
VAR CHAR(10)

(
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [Database]
WHERE [condition 1]
AND [condition 2]
)
INTO :VAR
```